# Does NetBIOS do any caching?

Tags: file-io, samba, unc, shared-directory, netbios

If I read a file from a UNC network share does Windows cache parts of that file?

For example: If I read the whole file byte for byte, will each read call result in a request over the network, or does Windows read larger blocks internally, and serve subsequent request from memory?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly contents of the file may be cached.

To make sure that all reads will be done against the actual file and not from any system buffer or disc cache one could use the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` in a call to [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can also disable caching for a shared resource using `net share <sharename> /cache:none`